# How to get OR permissions instead of AND in REST framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

It seems that permission classes are ANDed when REST framework checks permissions. That is every permission class needs to return True for permission to be granted. This makes things like "if you are a superuser, you can access anything, but if you are a regular user you need explicit permissions" a bit hard to implement, you cannot just return False, it will fail the whole stack. Is there a way to maybe short-circuit permissions? Something like "if this permission is granted, stop checking?" or some other way to deal with cases like that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you might be able to use `django-rules` library here. [Link](https://github.com/dfunckt/django-rules)

It is a rule based engine very similar to decision trees and it can be easily integrated with permissions_class framework of DRF.

The best part is you can perform set operations on simple permissions and create complex permissions from them.

Example

```
>>> @rules.predicate
>>> def is_admin(user):
...     return user.is_staff 
...


>>> @rules.predicate
>>> def is_object_owner(user, object):
        return object.owner == user
```

Predicates can do pretty much anything with the given arguments, but must always return True if the condition they check is true, False otherwise.
Now combining these two predicates..

```
is_object_editable = is_object_owner | is_admin
```

You can use this new predicate rule `is_object_editable` inside your has_permissions method of permission class.

Comment: When I first saw this library, I also had same reaction. I have been using it almost for every project.

Answer (score 60):

Now DRF allows permissions to be composed using bitwise operators: & -and- and | -or-.

[From the docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/):

> Provided they inherit from `rest_framework.permissions.BasePermission`, permissions can be composed using standard Python bitwise operators. For example, IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly could be written:

```py
from rest_framework.permissions import BasePermission, IsAuthenticated
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView

class ReadOnly(BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return request.method in SAFE_METHODS

class ExampleView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated|ReadOnly,)

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        content = {
            'status': 'request was permitted'
        }
        return Response(content)
```

Edited:  Please note there is a comma after `IsAuthenticated|ReadOnly`.

Comment: Hi mehamasum, do you try this "|" in the code. Yes, I found the document say that "|" can be used, but I got the error "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'type' and 'type'"

Comment: @flytofuture may be you are using and older version of DRF? Could you try upgrading the package and try it again?

Comment: @flytofuture, `|` and `&` came in [3.9](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/community/3.9-announcement/#composable-permission-classes), with `~` following in [3.9.2](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/community/release-notes/#392)

Comment: Please note there is a comma after `IsAuthenticated|ReadOnly`.  Otherwise, will get an error: `TypeError: 'OperandHolder' object is not iterable`

Comment: Is it possible to do something like this somehow?
permission_classes = ((IsAuthenticated) | (ReadOnly & HasPermissionToken))

Comment: Can we used 3 permissions like
permission_classes = [IsReadOnly|IsOwner|IsAdminUser] ?

Comment: It doesn't work for me; The first permission is tested and return False, and the second permission isn't tested. Howerver, the view is executed

Answer (score 2):

You need to build your own [custom http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#custom-permissions](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#custom-authentication) as described in the docs.

Something like:

```
from rest_framework import permissions

class IsAdminOrStaff(permissions.BasePermission):
    message = 'None of permissions requirements fulfilled.'

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return request.user.is_admin() or request.user.is_staff()
```

Then in your view:

```
permission_classes = (IsAdminOrStaff,)
```

Comment: I know. But then the problem is that once this permission class returns False, permission to the resource is denied. The logic I want is "if you are a regular user, you need to have explicit permission to the resource, if you are admin, you can do whatever". And I am trying to avoid adding "if request.user.is_superuser" to every single custom permission class I have. I have edited the question to make this clearer.

Answer (score 2):

Aside from the custom permission which is simpler approach mentioned in the [earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35557412/764592), you can also look for an existing [3rd party](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#third-party-packages) that handle a much complex permission handling if necessary.

As of Feb 2016, those handling complex condition permission includes:

- [rest_condition](https://github.com/caxap/rest_condition#example)
- [djangorestframework-composed-permissions](https://djangorestframework-composed-permissions.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#permission-sets)

Comment: Custom permissions don't work for the logic I am trying to do. I will look at the libraries you linked, although I hoped there was some way to do the things I want natively.

Comment: Custom permission should work. Custom permission is giving you the lower control that you can do almost anything you can think of

Comment: Read my question. The problem with permissions, custom or not, is that if one of them fails permission is denied. What I want to implement is "if you are a regular user, check that you have permissions X, Y and Z. If you are an admin you can do whatever". It seems that to implement it using custom permissions, I either need to add "if admin" clause to every permission check I have or implement boolean logic myself somehow.

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to add another [permission class](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/) which combines existing classes the way you want it, e.g.:

```
class IsAdmin(BasePermission):
    """Allow access to admins"""
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        return request.user.is_admin()


class IsOwner(BasePermission):
    """Allow access to owners"""
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        request.user.is_owner(obj)


class IsAdminOrOwner(BasePermission):
    """Allow access to admins and owners"""  
    def has_object_permission(*args):
        return (IsAdmin.has_object_permission(*args) or
                IsOwner.has_object_permission(*args))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a generic solution:

```
from functools import reduce
from rest_framework.decorators import permission_classes
from rest_framework.permissions import BasePermission


def any_of(*perm_classes):
    """Returns permission class that allows access for
       one of permission classes provided in perm_classes"""
    class Or(BasePermission):
        def has_permission(*args):
            allowed = [p.has_permission(*args) for p in perm_classes]
            return reduce(lambda x, y: x or y, allowed)

    return Or


class IsAdmin(BasePermission):
    """Allow access to admins"""

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        return request.user.is_admin()


class IsOwner(BasePermission):
    """Allow access to owners"""

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        request.user.is_owner(obj)


"""Allow access to admins and owners"""


@permission_classes((any_of(IsAdmin, IsOwner),))
def you_function(request):
    # Your logic
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to separate them out with `|` in `permission_classes` attribute or `get_permissions` method, but if you have complex rules, you can specify those rules in the `check_permissions` method in the viewsets class that you are defining. Something like this:

```
class UserProfileViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProfileSerializerBase
    
    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       # Create rules here

    def get_permissions(self):
        if self.action == "destroy":
            # Only Super User or Org Admin can delete record
            permission_classes = [SAPermission, OAPermission]

    def check_permissions(self, request):
    """
    Original check_permissions denies access if any one of the permission
    classes returns False, changing it so that it would deny access only if
    all classes returns False
    """
       all_permissions = []
       messages = []
       code = []
       for permission in self.get_permissions():
           all_permissions.append(permission.has_permission(request, self))
           messages.append(getattr(permission, "message", None))
           code.append(getattr(permission, "code", None))
       if True in all_permissions:
           return
       message = ",".join(i for i in messages if i)
       self.permission_denied(
           request,
           message=message if message else None,
           code=code[0],
       )
```